# ¿Cómo controlar excepción de conexión con pymsql?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Estoy creando un script para conectarme al servidor mysql y poder manipular las tablas, una especie de workbench en terminal.
Se necesita la conexión pero si ingreso credenciales inválidas no puedo manejar la excepción

```
(1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

El objetivo es que vuelva a solicitarlas. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
from getpass import getpass
import pymysql

def createConnection():
    host = input("Host: ")
    user = input("User: ")
    password = getpass("Password: ")
    db = None

    try:

        connection = pymysql.connect(host = host, user = user, password = password, database = db)

    except Exception as e:

        print("Error ...")
        print(e)
```

Comment: porque no llamas la clase de nuevo luego del print(e)?

Comment: @edsantoshn ¿a cual clase debería llamar?

Comment: despues del print(e) podrias llamar createConnection()... pero era funcion